# Python HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8') error

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

When I print this I get:
`['Ordinateur', 'Impression', 'Tablette & TÃ©lÃ©phonie ', 'MultimÃ©dia',...]`
What I want instead comes from the following
`['Ordinateur', 'Impression', 'Tablette & Téléphonie ', 'Multimédia',...]`

I m looking to scrape list of data from the header of a website correctly
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk
from lxml import html
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from time import sleep
import csv
import os
import re


             
index="https://www.disway.com/"
p=requests.get(index)
pages_s=[]
script= html.fromstring(p.text,parser=html.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-16'))

pages_s.extend(script.xpath('//*[@id="7ea42b1d-f4c2-41af-9908-eaaec09f308c"]/li/a/text()'))
pages_s.extend(script.xpath('//*[@id="7ea42b1d-f4c2-41af-9908-eaaec09f308c"]/li/ul/li/a/text()'))
print(pages_s)
```

Comment: Where is the usage of Selenium here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` thinks the web page is encoded in `ISO-8859-1` but it is really UTF-8.  The web page doesn't declare the content encoding correctly.  Use `p.content` to get the raw bytes of the request, and decode it as UTF-8 instead:

```py
from lxml import html
import requests

index = "https://www.disway.com/"
p=requests.get(index)
pages_s = []
script = html.fromstring(p.content,parser=html.HTMLParser(encoding='utf8'))

pages_s.extend(script.xpath('//*[@id="7ea42b1d-f4c2-41af-9908-eaaec09f308c"]/li/a/text()'))
pages_s.extend(script.xpath('//*[@id="7ea42b1d-f4c2-41af-9908-eaaec09f308c"]/li/ul/li/a/text()'))
print(pages_s)
```

Console output:

```py
['Ordinateur', 'Impression', 'Tablette & Téléphonie ', 'Multimédia', 'Accessoires', 'PC portable', 'PC bureau', 'Tout en un ', 'Options', 'Imprimante', 'Scanner', 'Terminal point de vente', 'Traceur', 'Copieur', 'Fax', 'Consommable', 'Options', 'Tablette', 'Smartphone ', 'Objet connecté', 'Casque & écouteurs', 'Options', 'Écran PC', 'Téléviseur', 'Vidéoprojecteur', 'Ecran projection', 'Visioconférence', 'Photo & vidéo', 'Options', 'Câble', 'Lecteur', 'Disque dur', 'Mémoire flash', 'Bagagerie', 'Clavier & souris', 'Barrette mémoire', 'Gaming', 'Audio', 'Webcam', 'Power bank', 'Multi-prise', 'Onduleur', 'Autres & divers']
```